# Ожидание завершения Activity

Tags: workflow, c#

Мы пытаемся прикрутить к серверу, написанному на базе Workflow Foundation, оповещение о прогрессе операций на клиенте.

Проблема в том, что я не нашёл никаких методов, которые позволили бы запустить Activity на выполнение и ждать её завершения в вызывающем потоке (в общем-то, просто запустить синхронно) - Workflow сама создаёт потоки, до которых из кода не доберёшься, и запускает Activity в них. Метода ожидания завершения тоже не нашлось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Для таких целей в `Workflow Foundation` используется [`AutoResetEvent`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd489463.aspx)*

Ваша задача - установить для объекта `Workflow Application` необходимые экшны на событий `Completed`, `Unloaded` и т.п и удостовериться в том, что все нормальные пути завершения вашей программы приводят к `AutoResetEvent.Set()`

После этого **для блокировки текущего потока** достаточно просто использования `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`